# Jenkins on Raspberry Pi not visible on LAN

Tags: networking, jenkins, debian, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am trying to run a headless jenkins/subversion Raspberry Pi on my home network.  I installed the Raspbian Server image found [here](http://sirlagz.net/2013/07/19/raspbian-server-edition-2-5/), and I have setup subversion with apache2.  I have installed jenkins with the tutorial found [here](http://antonylees.blogspot.com/2012/08/running-jenkins-ci-on-raspberry-pi.html).  I have also changed the HTTP_HOST in the jenkins config to 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1.  I am still not able to reach jenkins when I type [insert-Rpi-IP]:8080 into the browser of my other machines connected to my home router. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're still looking for a solution on this, first take a look to see if that port is open/availalble.

The built-in way to check is with netstat:

```
  netstat -an |grep LISTEN

tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

however I prefer the tool lsof as it provides more detail on what is connected to the port/ (> sudo apt-get install lsof)

```
  sudo lsof -ni |grep LISTEN

java      32292     jenkins  149u  IPv6 49966390      0t0  TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)
```